# Why the general formula of Taylor series for $\ln(x)$ does not work for $n=0$?

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I need to find the taylor series for $\ln(x)$ about $a = 2$, and I have find the following solution, but I don't understand why the general formula does not work for $n = 0$.

[image]

Comment: If you substitute $n=0$ in for the general term, you must compute a $(-1)!$, which is not properly defined.

Comment: The proof by induction of $f^{(n)}(x)=(-1)^{n-1}(n-1)!/x^n$ starts at $n=1$.

Answer (score 1):

The general formula would be $\frac{(-1)^{0+1} (-1)!}{2^0} = -(-1)!$. The factorial of $-1$ is undefined, so the general formula isn't defined for $n=0$. However $f^{(0)}(2) = f(2) =\ln 2$. That's what is meant by "not working".

Note that this is closely related to $\int x^{n-1}\ \mathrm dx = \frac1n x^n$ wich is also not defined for $n=0$ but $\int x^{-1} \ \mathrm dx = \ln x$.

Comment: @Xenomorph FYI I didn't downvote your question. Some users disapprove of Mathematical text posted as a picture because that makes it unsearchable for future reference.